# Calling function from typescript in html not working

Tags: javascript, html, django, typescript

Hey im using a django and wanted to use typescript for a specific function I need for my application.

Here is my typescript file:

testselector.ts:

```
getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
      console.log('a');
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      console.log('b');
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return text;
}
```

And here is my html where I want to call the function:

```
{% extends "base_generic2.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <script src="textselector.js"></script>

  <div id="app" onmouseup="getSelectionText()">
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

For some reason it doesnt find getSelectionText() and I dont really know why?

**EDIT:**

Here are the errors popping up for  my typescript:

Error:(2, 3) TS2304: Cannot find name 'getSelectionText'.

Error:(7, 27) TS2339: Property 'selection' does not exist on type 'Document'.

Error:(7, 49) TS2339: Property 'selection' does not exist on type 'Document'.

Error:(9, 27) TS2339: Property 'selection' does not exist on type 'Document'.

Error:(2, 22) TS1005: ';' expected.

Comment: Is the function defined in a namespace? Is that the WHOLE content of the file?

Comment: Yes, I also get some TS2304 and TS2339 Errors for some reason, maybe thats whats causing it?

Comment: Could you post the errors you are getting (with the message), always helps to post the complete description of the issue ..

Comment: Hm but if that is the WHOLE content of your file, it's not syntactically correct, you are using method syntax for a simple function .. Try `function getSelectionText() { ... }`

Comment: yea that was it lol, thanks Titian :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your Typescript:

```
    window.getSelectionText = function(){
        var text = "";
        if (window.getSelection()) {
          text = window.getSelection().toString();
          console.log('a');
        } else if (window.getSelection() && window.getSelection().type != "Control") {
          console.log('b');
          text = document.getSelection().createRange().text;
      }
      return text;
    }
```

‌